# Are questions about the Google Play Developer Console on-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

Google Play's "Developer Console" website allows people to publish and maintain Android apps (screenshot below).

I have a question "How to do XYZ in Google Play Developer Console", but I fear it will be closed.
It is a website, but a website that smells like programming or Android.

Google-Play-related questions are already off-topic on Stackoverflow and [Android Enthusiasts](https://android.stackexchange.com/faq#what-about-other-android-related-questions).

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In my opinion, this should be on topic on this website, since it covers an aspect related to the use of a web application, which in your case is referring to the Google Play Developer Console, which indeed is a website. I am not too sure about what the other people think about this though.

Comment: Live test: http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/39320/android-play-developer-console-cant-reply-to-user-comments

Comment: And looks like it *is* accepted to be on-topic.